# script that contains matplotlib doesn't run in CMD

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this script:

```
# coding=utf8
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\201_b.csv', sep = ',', encoding = "utf-8")
passw = input('Password').upper()
if passw == 'A':
    df = x[x['project'].str.contains('ek')]
    #print(df)
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10)) 
    plt.bar(df['user'], df['dates'], color="blue")
    plt.show()

elif passw =='B':
    df = x[x['project'].str.contains('yf')]
```

I typed in cmd: `python file.py`
 and the program seems to run and then stops. Before the `matplotlib` lines everything worked fine. Now it doesn't even ask for the input.

I even tried this :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [10,34,56,45,51],'user':['user1','user2','user3','user4','user1']})
plt.bar(df['user'], df['number'], color="blue", linewidth =2, edgecolor='black' , alpha = 0.2)
plt.show()
x=input() #to deter it from closing - but no effect at all.
```

which is simpler and does the same thing. Runs and then nothing.No image shown.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No it seems to run and then stops

Comment: Maybe the programm is waiting for your input? Running it works fine for me. What happens, when you type 'A' or 'B' [Enter]? It does print Password at your machine?

Comment: It isn't waiting for input. Before the matplotlib lines it worked and asked : `Password` and waited for input as noraml now simply runs for 1 sec and then stops.

Answer (score 0):

x = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\user\Desktop\201_b.csv", sep = ",", encoding = "utf-8") can you try like that without the `r` before your filepath.

Comment: did you tried also plt.figure(1)? you can in your cmd try to typed only python, then import matplotlib like you did and type plt.figure(1) if the problem persist upgrade your matblotlib by using pip